# Can't get hyperlinks to work on iPhone

Tags: iphone

I'm using Microsoft Outlook to build html email with inserted pictures (jpgs).  When I apply a hyperlink to the images, they work fine on PCs running Outlook, Nook and iPod Touch.  They don't work on iPhones.  What happens on the iphone is when the hyperlinks are pressed, a screen comes up with several options like Copy, Print, Facebook..., but no Open like I see on an iPod Touch.  I don't know how to correct this.  Can anyone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the image type? Maybe it's not supported by iPhone.

Where does this image appear (web browser, email)? Some apps require specific command to fire an event on clicking.

If it's in mobile safari, is it a simple `<a href link? http: protocol`? Is it going anywhere that apple redirects (google maps, itunes, etc). or is it dependant on Javascript or flash?

Comment: The email is built in Outlook so the image is chosen from my PC and inserted into the email.  I have looked at the source code and the img is wrapped in an "a" tag properly.  The image displays correctly on the iphone, the hyperlink just isn't recognized like it is by other email clients.

Comment: How are you viewing the image? In the default mail app or through Safari? Also, what is the type of the image?

Comment: Viewing in default mail app.  The image is a jpg.